# Why can I not address a specific location in a Ruby string for which I've specified a capacity?

Tags: ruby

I want to create a new `String`, and assign to specific locations within that `String` without having to specify any content for that `String` in advance. I thought, from reading [the docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-c-new), that I ought to be able to do the following:

```
> n = String.new(capacity: 30)
> n[29] = 'G'
> puts "'#{n}'"
=> '                             G'
```

Instead, this raises an `IndexError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):25
        1: from (irb):25:in `[]='
IndexError (index 29 out of string)
```

I can, of course, do:

```
> n = ' ' * 30
```

and this does most of what I intend, save that it violates the spirit of what I'm trying to do, in that it's to be the input to a new `Magick::Image` via `import_str()`, so there would be a risk that the resulting image would be corrupted in some way (a risk I'd prefer to take is that the relevant element is nil and causes `import_string()` to fail spectacularly).

My reason for approaching the problem this way is that I am creating the new `String` from an existing `String`, but addressing the elements of the new string in order is a problem I'd prefer to avoid.

I can, of course, use an `Array` representation of the `String`, but this seems likely to be less efficient.

Am I missing the point of this variation on instantiating a Ruby `String`? Where are examples of usage that use the `capacity` keyword to create a `String` without an existing `String` of the same length? Am I stuck using either a pre-existing `String` of the right length, doing this by working through an `Array` representation of the `String`, or building it in order?

Comment: "*there would be a risk that the resulting image would be corrupted in some way*" How so?

Comment: I can't find an `import_str` nor `import_string` method of [Magick](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rmagick/Magick). Could you provide a reference?

Comment: `'%30s'%'G'` will produce the desired string `"                             G"`

Comment: When a string is defined with [String::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-c-new) the `:capacity` option only effects performance. It looks like you want `str = ' '*10 #=> "          "`.

Answer (score 2):

String capacity is only a control of its internal memory buffer. It's a performance optimization. From [String.new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-c-new)...

> The optional capacity keyword argument specifies the size of the internal buffer. This may improve performance, when the string will be concatenated many times (causing many realloc calls).

It does not have an effect on the string size itself. The string is still of length 0. [`String#[]=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) *replaces* content, it will not fill in spaces for you.

If you want a String of 30 spaces, use `' ' * 30`.

Comment: Alternatives `''.rjust(30)` (or `ljust`), `'%30s'%''`, `Array.new(30,' ').join` and esoterically  `''.concat(*[32]*30)`,`32.chr*30`, `?\s*30`